# use_config() is not changing my python configuration in R reticulate

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I'm new to the `reticulate` package in `R` and i'm having an issue. I'm specifying the python version I want to use (anaconda3 - python3.7) using `use_python` but it's not working.

This is my code:

```
    library(reticulate)

    sys <- import("sys")

    sys$version
    [1] "2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)]"

    use_python("/anaconda3/bin/python3", required = TRUE)

    sys$version
    [1] "2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)]"
```

In the terminal, i entered the command `which python` and shows me: 
/anaconda3/bin/python

Also when I check for `py_config() in R console` i get:
[py_config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFnOj.png)

But when I use `py_discover_config()` in R console i get:
[py_discover_config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5cCU.png)

How can I use this python3.7 version in reticulate because I cant load any module of my anaconda3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.

For anyone who has the same issue.

```
library(reticulate)
use_python("pathToPython", required = TRUE)
```

Then you can try

```
py_config()
```

And should be working. It was only the order of the commands.